# How to write this code without using the strtok() and strlen() functions?

Tags: c++

How to write the below code without using the `strtok()` and `strlen()` functions, how can they be replaced?

```cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[50];                  
    
    char* temp;             

    cout << "Input string: ";

    cin.getline(str, 50, '\n');       

    temp = strtok(str, " "); // temp адресс первого пробела

    while (temp != NULL)           
    {
        if (strlen(temp) % 2 == NULL)           
            cout << temp << '\t';
    
        temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to replace them, what's the issue? And is recoding them yourself an option?

Comment: "Do this, but without the obvious tools" gives a strong impression of a homework assignment. That is not a problem, but you might want to study https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions If this is not about homework, then in order to have people focus on your problem you should put minds at rest by explaining what prevents you from using the obvious tools.

Comment: Use `std::string`.

Comment: This looks like an exercise in writing loops and your own functions.

Comment: @OctaveL becouse this is my homework, the teacher requires

Comment: @Дарья what is the actual assignment?  There are MANY ways this code can be re-written to not use those functions, but WHICH WAY is your teacher expecting you to use exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Both `strtok` and `strlen` are C-isms that have good C++ alternatives, such as using streams and string.

Also, `NULL` should not be used as numerical `0`, in the test for even length strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::getline;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;

int main() {
    cout << "Input string: ";
    auto s = string{};
    getline(cin, s);

    auto ss = stringstream{s};
    auto word = string{};
    char const* sep = "";

    while (ss >> word) {
        if (word.length() % 2 == 0) {
            cout << sep << word;
            sep = "\t";
        }
    }

    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: and you can write something simpler

Comment: @Дарья • the way to make a program simpler is by refactoring the code to make functions that are one unit of work.  The predicate could be pulled out to `is_even_length` and the output loop could be pulled out `print_words_if` passing in the output stream, the input stream, and the predicate function.